# Why only three memory addresses are shown in memory leak?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, profiling, memory-leak-detector

I have written following code to intentionally create memory leak.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    while(1)
    {
        char *ch1 = new char[10];
        char *ch2 = new char[5];
        char *ch3 = new char[2];
        Sleep(5);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have taken logs using *LeakDiag* and make following graph using *LDGrapher*.

Now, my question is why only three address are shown in leak graph? I am keep on creating new pointers in `while(1)`, so I am leaking memory at lots of addresses?

[image]

Comment: Presumably the leaks are aggregated by call site?

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry I didn't understand it.

Comment: There are 3 places in your code where you leak memory.  You see those 3 places.  They are *code* addresses, not data addresses.  They differ so much because of the /ZI compile option.

Comment: @HansPassant +1 If it could have in answer section, I would accept it as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inclusion of windows.h "i assume u r running this on a windows box"
*memory managament in windows is much smart as compared to linux .

Try running the same program in linux and redraw the graph to see the differece